# I can't seem to connect with mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am new to mongoDB. I am a student trying to complete an exercise. I need to connect to a mongo database and seed that database with starter data. There is more to the project but I will tackle that when I get the connection/seeding problem solved.

Here are the environment particulars:

- mongo -- version 3.6.2 installed with brew
- macOSX High Sierra 10.13.3
- app written in node/express
- seeder is the npm package used for seeding (in theory anyway)
- IDE -- VSCode using Integrated Terminal as a CLI
- Just for thoroughness, restarted mongo by brew services restart
  mongodb
- start script = npm start ("nodemon ./start")
- link to the gist file:
  https://gist.github.com/dhawkinson/374e6e4cb79fb1eb2b8db11ede2af4b3

I get the following two console.logs 

`Express server is listening on port 5000
courseRatingDB connection established`

which you can see in the gist, but I get nothing else, no errors thrown, no syntax errors, no connection, no seeding. Can anyone tell me why, and how to fix it?

Comment: The mongoose-seeder package seems no longer be maintanied and there's a closed issue on github similar to yours that was never fixed. You may want to try another package for seeding.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/courseRatingDB', { useMongoClient: true });
mongoose.Promise = bruebird
```

before

```
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 5000);
```

and yeah, I double commentary about `const seeder = require('mongoose-seeder');`